# Type the password when doing a DELETE request

Tags: rest, http, backend

We want to enable the user to delete their account from the app.

The user needs to type in the password and send the password along with the DELETE request.

What would be the best approach of doing that?

Would I send the password on the body or would I send it as a parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR - you probably want to use a DELETE with no message body and the secret hand shake copied into a request header.

---

> Would I send the password on the body

Probably not this

> A payload within a DELETE request message has no defined semantics; sending a payload body on a DELETE request might cause some existing implementations to reject the request. -- [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.5)

An important concept in [REST](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) is the [uniform interface](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_5), a constraint that all resources should understand messages the same way.  One of the properties that this gives us is the ability to use general purpose components (browsers, caches); everything "just works" because messages and their semantics have been standardized.

If what you want is "like DELETE, but with a semantically significant payload", then the right answer would be to create a define a new method token, and then work through the process of standardizing the semantics of the method, [registering the token](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-8.1), and driving adoption.

The good news: HTTP already has a method token to use when the semantics of your request aren't worth standardizing: [POST](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post).

---

> or would I send it as a parameter

Not this either.  There are at least two problems here.

URI are first and foremost *identifiers*, and that means that they appear in a lot of contexts (like access logs, and browser histories) where the exposure of private or sensitive information would be unfortunate.

The bigger problem is that, if you change the identifier by adding parameters to it, then as far as general purpose components are concerned you are referencing a *different* resource.

```
DELETE /foo
DELETE /foo?password
```

Those are, from the perspective of a general purpose component, two *different* resources, and there is absolutely no reason that deleting one resource should impact the other in any way.  So things like [cache invalidation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4) don't "just work".

---

If you are trying to get users to re-authenticate in order to perform a delete operation, then you should presumably look at how you are currently authenticating them, and whether or not that mechanism gives you a way to invalidate the current credentials.

On the other hand, if you are just trying to collect a "yes, I really mean it" phrase, then that information should be either copied into the request body, like any other form data (which means you need to either use POST, or define a new method token) or copied into a *header* that you include with the request.

The basic purpose of request headers is to [modify request semantics](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5), and they are designed to be [extensible](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2.1)

> These requirements allow HTTP's functionality to be enhanced without requiring prior update of deployed intermediaries.

As with method tokens, there is a [standardization process](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-8.3) if you wanted to drive adoption.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it does not matter a lot, except if you expect the password to contain non ASCII parameters - which is always cause of nightmares.

HTTP makes no provision to describe the encoding of the query string, while it is possible to explicitely use an unicode encoding in the body. But as **you** can specify the protocol, you can decide that the query string contains the xxx encoded byte string of the password.

Another major difference is that the query string is limited in size while the body is not. But very large passwords are not so common so it should not be a real problem.

Long story made short: I only see that as a matter of taste and a design decision (provided you explicitely specify the query string encoding).